# `this` undefined in vue-router beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to access the session in vue-router via`this.a.app`, but it pops out 1 error.
After i debug, i found out that `this` is undefined.
this is the code im using to show `this`.

I had tried to use `function(to, from, next) {...}` instead of es6 syntax, but `this` is still undefined.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.meta.isPublic){
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(this)
  }
  next()
})
```

Is there any configuration i need to make so that i can access `this` in vue-router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use access "this" inside router beforeEach hook, but in a different way. The router has the root instance from where it is inserted

> User router.app it is pointing to "this" (the root Vue instance)

```
 router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.meta.isPublic){
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(router.app)
  }
  next()
})
```

Comment: but i couldn't access the session via `router.app`

Comment: Is this only to access specific values or complete vue instance

Comment: i want to access the session in complete vue instance

Comment: How exactly you are storing the session , in local storage or in vue store?

Comment: i'm using the library `vue-session`

Comment: Just do console.log(router.app.$session.exists()) inside beforeEach. You can access session inside router

Comment: the issue had been solved, but i'm not sure how. I just continued to develop other pages, when i come back to this issue, its working out of the sudden

Answer (score 0):

My best solution is to use Vue's [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

```
<script> // ignore this tag, it's just for hightlight
      router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        // console.info('TO', to, 'FROM', from)
         Vue.nextTick(() => {
           if (newTerm !== oldTerm) {
             router.app.getEasy(newTerm)
           }
         })

         next()
      })
</script>
```