# How to get cookie in Vue Router in Vue 3? this undefined in router/index.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session-cookies, vuejs3

Use case: Vue3 app using express as API backend. Express uses express-sessions to establish a server-side session which is sent to the browser and received in every subsequent request.

I'm trying to create a route guard to prevent access to certain routes if the session cookie doesn't exist.

```
"vue": "^3.0.11",
"vue3-cookies": "1.0.1",
```

I've installed the following NPM package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-cookies

Then in `main.js`

```
import VueCookies from 'vue3-cookies'
app.use(VueCookies);
```

Then in `router/index.js`

```
function requireAuth(to,from,next){
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.$cookies.get('_ga'))
  next();
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'ProtectedRoute',
    component: ProtectedRoute,
    beforeEnter:requireAuth
  }

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

Error: [Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: TypeError: Cannot read property '$cookies' of undefined
```

I've tried

```
this.$cookies.get('_ga')
Vue.$cookies.get('_ga')
window.$cookies.get('_ga')
```

None work.

I've also tried importing Vue into the index.js file but it fails, probably because in Vue3 you cannot import Vue into a component [Vue.js 3: Cannot import Vue global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653373/vue-js-3-cannot-import-vue-global-object)

The problem seems to be that this,Vue and window are all undefined. I've also tried the solution here [`this` undefined in vue-router beforeEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443301/this-undefined-in-vue-router-beforeeach)

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  console.log(router.app); //still undefined!
});
```

Help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why are you trying to get cookies in beforeEach?

Comment: Also maybe the problem is with the package, have you tried to use `document.cookie`? and see if it outputs something?

Comment: Your context is wrong, I think you could try with Vue.$cookies (import Vue first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vue Router 4 removes `router.app`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-router-app), but you could add it yourself when setting up the router:

```js
// main.js
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
router.app = app

app.mount('#app')
```

Then in the router config script, you could use that reference to get at `app.config.globalProperties.$cookies` (the global added by `vue3-cookies`):

```js
// router.js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

function requireAuth(to, from, next) {
  const { $cookies } = router.app.config.globalProperties
  console.log('_ga', $cookies.get('_ga'))
  next()
}

export default router
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-vuecookies-with-vuerouter-4-bu5y2?file=/src/router.js)

Comment: Thank you! Is this the right/vue way of doing this? it seems a little hacky.

Comment: The "right" way is debatable, but I agree it's not ideal. The [Vue Router docs recommend this way](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-router-app) of attaching `app` to `router`, so I'd say it's a "vue" way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```js
//router.js
import { useCookies } from "vue3-cookies";
const { cookies } = useCookies();

console.log(cookies.get('...'));
```

Comment: I tried this in my vue 3 app, its not working. I use options API like below
data(){ return { cookies : useCookies(), } }  then
access it in mounted method like this.cookies.set('token','testing')

But its not working

Answer (score 3):

Following what tony19 provided, I found another way that worked for me.
They removed `router.app` and it seems trying to add it myself doesn't work.
So instead, I just... exported the `app` instance from my main.js:

```
// main.js
export { app };
```

and imported in the router:

```
// router.js
import { app } from '...'
```

Now I could access the app instance's config, including `$cookies.get` method:

```
console.log(app.$cookies.get('...'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will help anybody, but Syll's answer (sorry, can't comment the answer, don't have enough rep) lead me to noticing something I did wrong and wasn't working for me: In my case I wasn't using {} when setting the const, so I had to call `.cookies()` method on the object returned by `useCookies()` from `vue3-cookies` library. Like this:

```js
import { useCookies } from "vue3-cookies";
const cookies_manager = useCookies();

console.log(cookies_manager.cookies.get('myCookieName'));
```

This should be avoidable by using `const { cookies } = useCookies();` (note the curly braces) instead.